# configuring mongodb - WTCheck.tThread writes on disk into WiredTiger.wt

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I've installed mongodb 4.4.3 on my Raspberry Pi and I've noticed there are some IO operations even though no client is connected and no queries from my side.
First I've noticed FTDC writing every ~8seconds, so I set `diagnosticDataCollectionEnabled: false`.
But there still remain writes into WiredTiger.wt (.turtle and index) every minute.
What does it do, is it some journal? Can I disable it?
It is my personal dev webserver, there won't be much writing/reading from my side, so I dont see the point in mongo doing some unnecessary writing, since it will be just slowly killing my SSD.
(Btw. I'm a nub, never really worked with mongo)

Answer (score 0):

storage.journal.commitIntervalMs  ( default=100ms , you can increase up to 500ms )

Comment: I've seen that in the docs, but idk how that could help me...? I dont wan't any writes into WiredTiger.wt, or at least not when nothing happens